# FullCalendar library FirstDay setting is not respected in different time zones

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timezone, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-6

I'm using fullCalendar library (version 6 the latest one) to create month calendar view in my react application.
I want to show my first day of week as Monday. For this I have used this setting : firstDay: 1. It works in some time zones. But If I change my time zone (In chrome by going to More Tools -> Sensors and choose a different location / time zone), some times it shows me Sunday as the first day of the week. From my side, I checked in IST and PDT (setting location as San Francisco in Chrome More Tools -> Sensors). In former, I get Monday as my first day and in latter one I get Sunday as my first day. I also tried to keep the same locale by passing it explicitly to my FullCalendar component, but that too doesn't work.

Minimum Reproducible Example Link : https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/cold-moon-q3fg4t?welcome=true

**

> Please use the chrome dev tools sensors to test, not the sandbox's dev tools
> one. I feel the sandbox's sensors are not working properly.

**

One another point to add : In my CalendarDayHeader component, I changed my code from :

```
  const dayIndex = day.date.getDay();
```

to this

```
  const dayIndex = day.date.getUTCDay();
```

With this change, I tried to simulated different time zones and it shows Monday in each time zone. But it gives me doubt as my Header now rendering days name using UTC. And all of my calendar uses user's local time zone (which is requirement in my case). My day cells dates too get rendered as per user's local time zone.

My doubt is won't it create a mismatch between aligning the weekdays name and below day cells dates ? Say a day falling on another day but appears below Monday or some another day.

Thanks.

Comment: Based on the [docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/firstDay) it sounds like you've done the right thing.
Could you add some code snippets to your question that show your current implementation. This way we'll be able to see if the error is in the usage or maybe a bug that needs to be addressed with the package owner.

Comment: Agreed. Please provide a [mre] of the issue. A description alone always leaves room for ambiguity. See also [ask]. You can [edit] your post. Thanks.

Comment: Also you have tagged fullcalendar 5. It is very much worth upgrading to the latest 6.x version to see if any bugs may have been fixed in the meantime.

Comment: @ADyson I have added the MRE please check the sandbox link and I'm already using the 6 version.
Thanks for the replies.

Comment: @JaredRolt I have added the MRE please check the sandbox link